# How do I get IntelliJ/PyCharm to recognize an active IPython kernel?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, ipython, pycharm, jupyter

I have used Jupyter notebooks for some time now without any problems. However I use IntelliJ for pretty much all my programming and wanted to try out moving my ipython workflow into IntelliJ. I followed the instructions provided [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/tutorial-using-ipython-jupyter-notebook-with-pycharm.html) and everything seems to work fine except when I go to run a cell it keeps trying to start the kernel even though the kernel should already be running.

[image: IntelliJ screenshot]

I can use the kernel in Jupyter like normal when I follow the link, but I can not use it from IntelliJ.

Comment: check out this link: https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2014/12/feature-spotlight-ipython-notebook-inside-an-ide/

Comment: @YamanAhlawat I followed an updated guide as shown in the question:
 https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/tutorial-using-ipython-jupyter-notebook-with-pycharm.html

The result is the same, IntelliJ does not recognise that the kernel is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got in touch with Jetbrains support and they told me this was a known issue with their Jupyter integration. However the latest version of the python plugin for IntelliJ seems to have fixed the issue.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-22032

Answer (score 3):

To make it work you should select a right interpreter in [Project Settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/configuring-available-python-interpreters.html). Seems like jupyter is installed on your system interpreter. 
Meanwhile it is recommended to use venv with pycharm(and python in general). 
If you created venv than you need to select python interpreter from that venv and it should do the job.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have the project set to use a venv with the jupyter dependency. https://i.imgbox.com/Xs7KETnX.png